# Sliding Drawer from left to right

Tags: android, menu, sidebar, sliding

I want to make Sliding Drawer to slide from the left.

I have a partial solution, but it only works on Android versions 3 or higher and I want to support 2.2. The solution is the property `android:rotation=180` in the Sliding Drawer component in XML.

Does anyone know how to do it or some similar effect to expand a menu and move the entire view to right?

Answer (score 0):

Using this,  http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-sliding-drawer/ it's MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer